# Wordpress pretty links using add_rewrite_rule()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks

I'm creating a Wordpress Woocommerce website and i want to make pretty links.

For example:

`http://maskshop.lt/parduotuve/?filter_pagal-efekta=drekinanti&query_type_pagal-efekta=or` to `http://maskshop.lt/efektas/drekinanti/or/`

This is my current code in functions.php:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^efektas/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=299&filter_pagal-efekta=$matches[1]&query_type_pagal-efekta=$matches[2]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

The main problem is that when i go to `http://maskshop.lt/efektas/drekinanti/or/` i get redirected to shop and none of filters be on(checked). I'm using filter widgets in shop page.

So, what could be the problem ?